# Pedestrian Re-identification during tracking

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition, tracking, visual-tracking

During the multi-camera tracking, there is a situation where one person moves from one camera's coverage area to another. In that case that person has to be re-identified(as the one from previous camera's previous view) in order to keep tracking the particular object. What is the easiest way to do this? Color matching? Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: This is a very hard problem and the subject of active research.

Comment: Are the cameras calibrated?